# finding duplicate in python by asking input from user

Tags: python, list, duplicates

Read in 10 numbers. As each number is read, print it only if it is not a duplicate, if the number is duplicate escape it and ask for another input until non duplicate values reach 10.
below is my code:

```
lst = []
for n in range(10):
    new_num = input("Enter any number: ")
    if new_num not in lst:
        lst.append(new_num)
        print(new_num)
    else:
        continue
print(lst)
```

I want it stop after `lst` reaches 10 numbers. But currently if there is any duplicate number input, the size of `lst` will be smaller then 10.
What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Does your code not work as intended?  Also, that `else: continue` is unnecessary.

Comment: Hi! You've quoted an assignment and shown code. What is _your question_?

Comment: You probably want to append _before_ checking if the number is already in `lst`.

Comment: no the code works perfectly i intended it in the ide.. but the problem is that it should ask for input until it gets 10 un-repeated or not duplicate values... i cant figure out how to do that.. this code asks for input 10 times but i want to have a list of 10 int values which are not duplicated from user

Comment: @msanford 1. Use a list to solve the following problem: Read in 10 numbers. As each number is read, print it only if it is not a duplicate of a number already read

Comment: Did you have a question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might want like this

```
lst = []
n=10
i=0
while i<n:
    new_num = input("Enter any number: ")
    if new_num not in lst:
        lst.append(new_num)
        print(new_num)
        i+=1
    else:
        continue 
print(lst)
```

Comment: I was going to post the same... I upvoted though, but just a quick question: why would you use ```continue```? It's not going to make the process faster

Comment: Actually he want a list of 10 values as a result. If he enter any duplicate value i.e previously entered value which is in list,it should prompt again and again without adding that in list untill the length of that list becomes 10.

Comment: @Asriel,we can get rid of continue but I thought minimum modification to his code so left as it was.

Comment: `while i<10` should be `while i<n` or just get rid of the `n=10`.

Comment: @wp-overwatch.com , in question its already mentioned "Read in 10 numbers". That's why I took 10 there else we can take one more input for list size.

Comment: What I mean is that you're creating the variable `n`, but you're not using it.

Comment: Thanks @wp-overwatch.com . I got it